# Joomla Showing plugins to some countries but not others

Tags: joomla

I currently have a joomla site, when logged in the extensions don't render and I see source code. But if I access the site from a different connection (3G) and don't login I don't see the source code.

Something is making the site non-render plugins on connections that have logged into joomla before.

[image: Visable source code]

Is there some kind of extension that may be causing this?

An example of the source that doesn't render:

```
 {source}
<div class="cshadow"></div>
{/source}
```

Comment: You'll need to at the very least specify which extensions they are. Maybe show the source code they are generating when they work.

Comment: I have done this in an edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some extensions that can show/hide content for specific countries in Joomla. But, are you sure the issue is not related to content being displayed only for logged in users (which is a basic Joomla functionality).

Forgive me if I misunderstood your question, if I did, then please provide more context so that I can help!